# Hash function for arrays of floats and ints in .NET

Tags: .net, dictionary, hash

I have a particular use case where I am wanting to hash several arrays of `float` and `int` together. I am writing a simulation where I want to memoize a function call. The function takes a `Settings` type as an input.

The values in the `Capacities` and `MaxRates` arrays are 64 bit floats restricted to a range of 0.0 to 1,000,000.0. The length of `Capacities` and `MaxRates` is also restricted to 0 to 100. `ValveState` is an `int` with values from 0 to 10.

I am aware that hashing arbitrary floats is a bad idea. In this particular use case though the values in `Settings` will be exact, bit for bit matches to previous combination of values. That is the reason I want to memoize a function call using a `Dictionary<Settings, 'Result>`.

The function call I want to memoize is expensive and takes up >90% of the runtime. The combination of values in `Settings` is frequently repeated and they are exact matches. No math is actually done with the values during the simulation so rounding error is not occurring. Early tests suggest that memoizing this function can lead to a 10x improvement in speed with no loss in accuracy.

I am working in F# but anything in .NET is acceptable since I can translate it. Here is an example of what the F# record looks like.

```ml
type Settings = {
    Capacities : array<float>
    MaxRates : array<float>
    ValveState : array<int>
} with
    override this.GetHashCode () = 
        // Your awesome suggestion here
```

Comment: CRC32 mabe? AFAIK there's no bult-in HashAlgorithm for CRC32, but you can surely find an implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HashCode.Combine` (available in netstandard 2.1) to combine hashes of all values in all three arrays.

```
open System

let hashArray (arr : 'T array) =
    let mutable hash = 0
    for x in arr do
        hash <- HashCode.Combine(hash, x)
    hash

[<CustomEquality; NoComparison>]
type Settings = {
    Capacities : array<float>
    MaxRates : array<float>
    ValveState : array<int>
} with
    override this.GetHashCode () =
        HashCode.Combine(
            hashArray this.Capacities,
            hashArray this.MaxRates,
            hashArray this.ValveState
        )

    override this.Equals(o : obj) =
        match o with
        | :? Settings as s ->
            this.Capacities = s.Capacities &&
            this.MaxRates = s.MaxRates &&
            this.ValveState = s.ValveState
        | _ ->
            false
```